# Aura if - isTrue parameter and multiple conditions

Tags: lightning, conditional, aura-if

I'm trying this code :

[image]

```
<!-- an exemple :
     isTrue='{!and(v.valueOneIsTrue, v.valueThreeIsTrue)}" >-->
<aura:if isTrue="{!AND((v._candidateDetails.contact.Nationalite__c != null), (v.editMode=='true'))}">
<!-- do something -->
</aura:if>
```

I'm having this issue :
[image]

Is it possible to use the Aura:if this way, or is it the limit ?
Is this (from [here](http://sfdcmonkey.com/2016/12/03/use-multiple-conditions-in-auraif/)) the only way :
[image]

Nb : rectify from screenshot --> editMode=='true'

Comment: Can you please edit your question to post a text version of the code? Also the screenshots here from other site is not too relevant here. If you need to callout, it will be good to just post the link here. As for your error, it seems you are trying to use `editMode` attribute without using it as `v.editMode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler is complaining because you're using assignment (`=`) instead of conditional operator (`==`), in second condition: (`editMode='true'`). Also `AND` function is case sensitive.

Second problem mentioned by [Jayant](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/54851/jayant-das) would give a problem at run time.

You need to change:

```
isTrue="{!AND(v._candidateDetails.contact.Nationalite__c != null), (editMode='true'))}"
```

to:

```
// not should if there is a typo as attribute _candidateDetails starts with an Underscore
isTrue="{!and(v._candidateDetails.contact.Nationalite__c != null), (v.editMode=='true'))}"
```

---

Can be more readable which is a matter of preference as:

```
isTrue="{!and(not(empty(v._candidateDetails.contact.Nationalite__c)), equals(v.editMode, 'true'))}"
```

Useful Reference: [Expression Functions Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm) in Lightning

Comment: Thanks, also one important thing I got wrong is the UpperCase : it does NOT work when tipping AND !
You have to use 'and'.

Comment: Oh you're right, thats the curse of switching between case sensitive and insensitive languages.

Comment: I agree, looks like nothing but I've lost minutes understanding where was my mistake there -after your help, again thanks